# How to get the sequence number of a tcp packet in netty?

Tags: java, tcp, sequence, netty, packet

Is it possible to access the sequence number of an incoming TCP-packet in netty? I want to uniquely identify each packet, even with the same payload.

Comment: It isn't possible in C, let alone Java, let alone Netty.

Comment: It is possible to get the sequence number of an incoming TCP packet, but you need access to the raw socket, which netty does not provide. I would reread the [netty docs](https://netty.io/4.1/api/) as you are trying to use a high-level networking library like a low-level networking library.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not possible in netty as it is not exposed in java.nio.* classes and we also not expose it in our JNI transport.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with Java or JNI. It isn't exposed in `java.nio.*` classes or JNI, or `java.net.*` classes either, because it isn't exposed in C TCP sockets either.

Comment: Well you can do it in C via SOCK_RAW and then implement all the rest by yourself. So I think my answer is not incorrect ;)